# a complicate example using loop invariant

Tags: loops

can anyone supply a complicate example using `loop invariant` example such as `sum(int n)` is so trivial that it can not show the power of `loop invariant`. I want a example that is not that obivious, and we can use method like `loop invariant` to solve it.

Comment: The point of SO is not to serve as a substitute for investigation - IOW, you do the work, we solve your problems

Comment: This question is so abstract!

Answer (score 2):

The [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-invariant_code_motion) example is quite good:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    x = y + z;
    a[i] = 6 * i + x * x;
}
```

Two invariant can be moved (y + z and x * x). The advantage of this example is that after LICM has been applied, you can apply other optimizations on the code to have something very easy.

There are plenty on papers/slides/courses about that, you sure can find a satisfying example.

Comment: thank for your preety advice for looking up examples in papers. In this question, I want to say, suppose a while loop is rather logically difficult and we can not program easily, I want to know whether `loop invariant` can help us.